# Force Visual Studio to show items in item group at any time in vbproj

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In a C# project (csproj), you can expand an item group (for example a form), regardless of the "Show All Files" setting:

[image]

On the other hand, in a VB.NET project(vbproj), you can only expand an item group if you set the "Show All Files" setting on:

[image]

It comes handy to have this kind of files visible when using Slow Cheetah for example:

[image]

I tried to manually add to items

```
<InProject>true</InProject>
```

with no effect.

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to show files in item group in a vbproj, regardless of the "Show All Files" setting, like in a csproj?